# Converting between RGB and HSL/HSV: What to do with overflows?

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, rgb, hsv, hsl

I've implemented some functions according to the HSL->RGB and HSV->RGB algorithms.
They mostly work fine, but I'm not sure what is the right thing to do then a color component overflows as a result of the conversion.

E.g., the red component ends up being `1.2` whereas the allowed range is `[0..1]`. If I multiply that by 255 I will obviously get a value that is invalid in the RGB world.

What is the correct way of handling this -- truncating (`if > 1 then set to 1`) or wrapping around (`if > 1 then substract 1`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible that the values ​​R, G and B come out of their range if you have properly implemented standard algorithms and inputs are in their ranges.

What algorithms you've implemented?

Comment: The ones from [wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL). Now that I've looked into it, they look quite different to their [English counterparts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space#From_HSL)...

Comment: See for example here: http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript